# Look I need to proof combinator

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Title: Transforming a Sequence to Obtain a Specific Set

**Question:**
Consider a sequence of integers
( k_1, k_2, k_3, …, k_p ) where ( k_1 >= k_2 >= k_3 >= … >= k_p ). The sum of this sequence is ( k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + … + k_p = n(n+1)/2 ). We are allowed to repeatedly take 1 from each integer in the sequence to form a new set. Can we prove that through this process, we can eventually obtain the set {1, 2, …, z}, where ( z ) is some positive integer?

**Example:**
Starting with the sequence (3, 3), the process unfolds as follows:
(3, 3) -> (2, 2, 2) -> (1, 1, 1, 3) -> (2, 4) -> (1, 2, 3)

This demonstrates that starting with ( (3, 3) ), we can eventually obtain ( {1, 2, 3} ).

How can we rigorously prove that this transformation is possible for any given sequence satisfying the stated conditions?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part.